# Flowplayer RTMP streaming, mp4, Amazon Cloudfront and iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, video-streaming, flowplayer

I've been working on a site where 2 video clips are streamed using Amazon Cloudfront and Flowplayer. You can see one video/page here: http://graemeclarkoration.org.au/gcorationp1.htm (works as a Highslide popup/modal window, hence the lack of adornment).

While it works in all browsers and Android devices, I can't get it to work on an iPad or an iPhone; the page opens fine and the video box appears but the video never loads.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix or even why the video won't load?

Edit: streaming an mp4.

MTIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ipad/iphone do not support RTMP streaming at this time.  You will need to either use rtsp or http instead of rtmp.

For specifying html5 rtsp streaming in safari on the ipad look at the section "Specifying Multiple Delivery Schemes" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm going to target Mobile Safari only and whack the video in html5. All other browsers (and devices) can stick with flowplayer.